# Which free tool/script i can use for user to download mp3 from website

Tags: php, flash

I have one website and few mp3 in one folder fro user to download.
Is there any flash or php script which shows the content of folder in nice gui way so that user can click on them and download them

Comment: Have you tried linking to them directly?

Comment: It works directly but i don't want to put code for every mp3 file.
It would be good if it automatically get that from folder

Comment: I take it a regular apache "browser" type view wouldn't work, were it just lists the contents of a folder with the files linked and downloable?

Comment: It can be done with flash and remoting

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the content using `DirectoryIterator` like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202175/php-script-to-loop-through-all-of-the-files-in-a-directory).