# PHP script to loop through all of the files in a directory?

Tags: php, file

I'm looking for a PHP script that loops through all of the files in a directory so I can do things with the filename, such as format, print or add it to a link. I'd like to be able to sort the files by name, type or by date created/added/modified. (Think fancy directory "index".) I'd also like to be able to add exclusions to the list of files, such as the script itself or other "system" files. (Like the `.` and `..` "directories".)

Being that I'd like to be able to modify the script, I'm more interested in looking at the PHP docs and learning how to write one myself. That said, if there are any existing scripts, tutorials and whatnot, please let me know.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086105/get-the-files-inside-a-directory/1086110#1086110

Answer (score 297, accepted):

You can use the [DirectoryIterator](http://de.php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.construct.php). Example from php Manual:

```
<?php
$dir = new DirectoryIterator(dirname(__FILE__));
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) {
        var_dump($fileinfo->getFilename());
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Note: many servers don't have SPL installed, so you won't be able to use the DirectoryIterator class (see my alternative post below). Use this if you can though!

Comment: Note[2]: Make sure you understand that the ``dirname()`` function above will  get the parent folder of whatever path you put there. In my case, I assumed dirname was a wrapper for the directory name/path, so it was not needed.

Comment: Also, if dirname it's a large filesystem, problems with memory are evident. On my case with 1 millons of files, app needs ~512M ram on memory_limit.

Comment: If you need the complete path like `/home/examples/banana.jpg` use `$fileinfo->getPathname()`

Comment: You can use !$fileinfo->isDir() to avoid action on directories

Comment: How does this example work? Does "DirectoryIterator(dirname(__FILE__))" search the entire folder hierarchy on a server? If so isn't that going to perform super slow?

Answer (score 51):

If you don't have access to DirectoryIterator class try this:

```
<?php
$path = "/path/to/files";

if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ('.' === $file) continue;
        if ('..' === $file) continue;

        // do something with the file
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you name a situation where you wouldn't have access to it?

Comment: A lot of legacy applications use PHP 4, which has no access to the DirectoryIterator.

Comment: Why '.' === $file? This isn't Java.

Comment: Dave... Nope it is matching the dots and does not continue if it doesn't match in PHP. Search for the difference between == and ===.

Answer (score 39):

Use the `scandir()` function:

```
<?php
    $directory = '/path/to/files';

    if (!is_dir($directory)) {
        exit('Invalid diretory path');
    }

    $files = array();
    foreach (scandir($directory) as $file) {
        if ($file !== '.' && $file !== '..') {
            $files[] = $file;
        }
    }

    var_dump($files);
?>
```

Answer (score 23):

You can also make use of `FilesystemIterator`. It requires even less code then `DirectoryIterator`, and automatically removes `.` and `..`.

```
// Let's traverse the images directory
$fileSystemIterator = new FilesystemIterator('images');

$entries = array();
foreach ($fileSystemIterator as $fileInfo){
    $entries[] = $fileInfo->getFilename();
}

var_dump($entries);

//OUTPUT
object(FilesystemIterator)[1]

array (size=14)
  0 => string 'aa[1].jpg' (length=9)
  1 => string 'Chrysanthemum.jpg' (length=17)
  2 => string 'Desert.jpg' (length=10)
  3 => string 'giphy_billclinton_sad.gif' (length=25)
  4 => string 'giphy_shut_your.gif' (length=19)
  5 => string 'Hydrangeas.jpg' (length=14)
  6 => string 'Jellyfish.jpg' (length=13)
  7 => string 'Koala.jpg' (length=9)
  8 => string 'Lighthouse.jpg' (length=14)
  9 => string 'Penguins.jpg' (length=12)
  10 => string 'pnggrad16rgb.png' (length=16)
  11 => string 'pnggrad16rgba.png' (length=17)
  12 => string 'pnggradHDrgba.png' (length=17)
  13 => string 'Tulips.jpg' (length=10)
```

Link:
http://php.net/manual/en/class.filesystemiterator.php

Answer (score 6):

You can use this code to loop through a directory *recursively*:

```
$path = "/home/myhome";
$rdi = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::KEY_AS_PATHNAME);
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($rdi, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST) as $file => $info) {
    echo $file."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) has provisions for sorting and pattern matching. Since the return value is an array, you can do most of everything else you need.

Comment: This is good unless you are dealing with a lot of files... > 10,000. You'll run out of memory.

Comment: @NexusRex: You shouldn't be reading 10,000 records from a database either, but that's out of scope as far as the question is concerned

Comment: Agreed! If reading from a database you can paginate with "limit" though—no such luck when you have a directory with 5 million XML files to iterate through.

Comment: There is SPL GlobIterator.

Comment: This is awesome for the correct use. In my case I want to purge the downloads folder each night for a small company website. I want to be able to have subdirectories in the downloads folder and this is the solution I was looking for. Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 4):

Most of the time I imagine you want to skip `.` and `..`. Here is that with
recursion:

```
<?php

$rdi = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('.', FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$rii = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($rdi);

foreach ($rii as $di) {
   echo $di->getFilename(), "\n";
}
```

https://php.net/class.recursivedirectoryiterator

Answer (score 2):

For completeness (since this seems to be a high-traffic page), let's not forget the good old [`dir()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dir.php):

```
$entries = [];
$d = dir("/"); // dir to scan
while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) { // mind the strict bool check!
    if ($entry[0] == '.') continue; // ignore anything starting with a dot
    $entries[] = $entry;
}
$d->close();
sort($entries); // or whatever desired

print_r($entries);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this as well

```
$path = "/public";

$objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($objects as $name => $object) {
  if ('.' === $object) continue;
  if ('..' === $object) continue;

str_replace('/public/', '/', $object->getPathname());

// for example : /public/admin/image.png => /admin/image.png
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a problem with using the accepted answer's suggestion of **[DirectoryIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.construct.php)**.  After all, just load up the documentation page for the iterator and see if you can find any problems -- in fact, look at the available methods.  Do you see any method for directoryiterator to determine if an entry in a folder is a folder or not?  Why is there no `isFolder()` or `isDirectory()` or anything that can be called on files?  There's `getFilename()`, but why can't I determine if I have another folder that needs another directoryiterator?

In that event, you need to use `is_dir()` in combination with `DirectoryIterator`.  Here is a recursive example that separates out files from folders and then recursively iterates over newly-discovered folders:

```
$dir = '/some_directory/';

function parseDir($dir) {
    foreach (new DirectoryIterator($dir) as $file) {
        if($file->isDot()) continue;
        $new_item = $dir . $file->getFilename() . '/';
        if(is_dir($new_item)) {
            print('Directory found!' . $new_item . PHP_EOL);
            parseDir($new_item);    # Recursion
        } else {
            print('File found!' . $new_item . PHP_EOL);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect. Check the documentation for [SpfFileInfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php). The methods `isDir` and `isFile` are publicly available

Comment: "*why can't I determine if I have another folder that needs another directoryiterator*" - Have a look at the [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)