# Batch rename images inside folders

Tags: php, batch-file, batch-rename, data-entry

I'm doing a data entry job and I need to rename all the images inside a bunch of folders. Instead of doing it manually I thought PHP could help.

Inside each folder is an image. I need to loop through all the folders, grab the image and rename it to it's parent folder's name. I know it's 100% possible but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to provide us with some code that illustrates your attempt before we can help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202175/php-script-to-loop-through-all-of-the-files-in-a-directory

Comment: A batch file can do it if we know the filenames.ext used and paths.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use two php's function: scandir and rename.

scandir: list all files of a directory

http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.scandir.php

Then, with "foreach", you can rename each file using rename

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.rename.php

Good look!!!