# Using filename to timestamp image

Tags: image, bash, timestamp, raspberry-pi

I have a ton of images that are all named after when they were taken (ie: 23_08_2016_23:34:21) and I want to add this string into the picture. I'm using raspberry pi, so this should be a script that I can just run and convert all the files in my folder (.jpg) into images with time-stamps in the bottom corner or so. I've looked at several softwares such as ffmpeg but I can't find whats right for me. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP to annotate images or overlay text onto images.  See http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.annotateimage.php

Comment: But how would I get it to use the filename as the overlay text and How  would I run this from a shell script?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202175/php-script-to-loop-through-all-of-the-files-in-a-directory for some good PHP code snippets that show how to loop through the files in a directory.  You can probably use one of these as a boilerplate for what you are doing.  In the body of the loop, you have the filename, and you can call the imagick function and pass it the filename.