# Why am I not getting the directory hierarchy?

Tags: php, directory

The following code is meant to display directories as well as sub directories within the directories and the files inside them. I used `chmod` function to gain access to directories.

This code runs but doesn't display the directory hierarchy, which means it is unable to list the sub directories and the files inside.

As I run the script, I get this warning :

```
Warning: chmod(): No such file or directory in E:\Installed_Apps\xampp\htdocs\dlist.php on line 5
```

-

```
#recursive function

function directory_f_lister($root) {
    $dir_list = scandir($root);
    for($var=0;$var<count($dir_list);$var++) {

        $bool = chmod($root.$dir_list[$var], 0777);

        if(is_readable($root.$dir_list[$var])) {
            if(is_dir($root.$dir_list[$var])) {
                if($dir_list[$var] === "." || $dir_list[$var] === "..") continue;
                echo "<h3>Name of directory $dir_list[$var]</h3>";
                echo "<br />";
                $dh = opendir($root.$dir_list[$var]);
                while(($name = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                    if(is_dir($root.$dir_list[$var].$name)) {
                        if($dir_list[$var] === "." || $dir_list[$var] === "..") continue;
                        echo "Name of directory : <strong> $name </strong>";
                        echo "<br />";
                        directory_f_lister($root.$dir_list[$var].$name);
                    }else {
                        echo $name;
                        echo "<br/>";
                    }
                }
            }
        } else { "<b>else statement <br /> </b>"; }
    }
}

directory_f_lister(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

What is the problem ? Why am I not getting the directory hierarchy ?

Comment: Isn't this error message really clear?

Comment: does it help ?? you must print_r($root.$dir_list[$var]) to check what path it returns or print_r(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/'.$dir_list[$var]);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202175/php-script-to-loop-through-all-of-the-files-in-a-directory something like this might help

Answer (score 0):

```
chmod(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/'.$dir_list[$var], 0777);
```

Comment: print your realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) and then concatenate the filename and folder path as necessary

Comment: that doesn't help ! Why would I use `dirname(__FILE__)` ? I want to print the directories starting from root `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`

Comment: Also, the statement `echo "<strong> $root.$dir_list[$var] </strong>"` prints like `\$AVG...$VAULT ` or `\.$AVG `

Comment: @saplingPro is that what you expect as output ? chmod expects real path instead of hardcoded path sometimes... did you try : **realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/'.$root.'/'$dir_list[$var];** and echoed it

Comment: yeah. but that gives the path from where the script is running

Comment: NO. I want to read all the directories and sub directories starting from the root. If its `E:\b\c\d\script.php`, start reading everything from `E:\\`