# (PHP) show available text file in xxx directory

Tags: php

i save edit log in txt files, my problem is
how to echo/show all available log/txt files in log directory

im already made function for read file

```
function readFile($filename) {
    $myfile = fopen("$filename", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    // Output one line until end-of-file
    while(!feof($myfile)) {
      echo fgets($myfile) . "<br>";
    }
    fclose($myfile);    
}
```

above code just function for readfile, my problem is show available files , thanks

Comment: [`glob`](http://php.net/glob) may help.

Comment: thanks, i will read that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at using `opendir()` or the `DirectoryIterator` class.

Similar question on Stack Overflow.

[PHP script to loop through all of the files in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202175/php-script-to-loop-through-all-of-the-files-in-a-directory)

Should get you going in correct direction.

Comment: This should be a vote to close as duplicate, just so you know ;)

Comment: Didn't know.. thanks :)

Comment: PS: Didn't know we could do that at all.. Pretty new on S.O, thanks again.

Comment: Ah, fair enough - close voting is apparently a 3,000 reputation perk. Still, at least you know now :)