# Flexslider php file list. echo. Massive time saver and flexible?

Tags: php, html, image, filesystems, flexslider

I want to use flexslider on my site, grabbing the images from a folder without having to list each and every file name in the folder (100+ images).

Is there some php script i can use to create something like an echo script that will make an " list?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make a php loop script....
For that you should have a DB table with the files path listed.

then you run the script `while $sqlarray = mysql_fetch_array($sql)`

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to create a PHP script that will look in a given folder and loop through all the files in that folder, outputting specific code for each.

```
<?php
$path = "/path/to/files";

if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
    echo "<ul>";

    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ('.' === $file) continue;
        if ('..' === $file) continue;

        echo "<li>".$file."</li>";
    }
    echo "<ul>";
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

It'll need tweaking to do exactly what you need but this can get you started.

See: [PHP script to loop through all of the files in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202175/php-script-to-loop-through-all-of-the-files-in-a-directory)