# Javascript array for all the files in a directory

Tags: javascript, php

I need to assign the list of all files of a directory (site_img) to a javascript array but not getting any luck.Can any one pls help .

i:e In the below code I want to assign the value of  filename to an javascript array in each iteration of the for loop.

```
<?php
foreach(glob('./site_img/*.*') as $filename){
 echo $filename;
 echo "<br>";
 }

?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP script to loop through all of the files in a directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202175/php-script-to-loop-through-all-of-the-files-in-a-directory)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With PHP, here is a snippet that I use on one of my sites:

```
<? 
        $fileList = '';
        $homePath = "a5780630"; //Dev
        $homePath = "a2092434"; //Live
        if ($handle = opendir('/home/'. $homePath .'/public_html/images/gallery/')) {

            /* This is the correct way to loop over the directory. */
            while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
                if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
                    $fileList = $fileList . ',' . $file;
                }
            }
            closedir($handle);
        }           
        ?>
```

That will give you a comma delimited string of all the files.  Then in JS:

```
<script language="javascript">
            var listOfImages = "<?php echo $fileList; ?>" 
            listOfImages = listOfImages.split(",");
</script>
```

Comment: thanks a lot .but I need to assign it to an array like this img = ['file1','file2','file3']

Comment: Uh, that's exactly what you will have.  A Javascript array named listofImages[list].

Comment: Cool.  Sorry you got a downvote on this one.  I didn't check for duplicates.  I knew I had the code written already, and just posted it...  I've been using that trick for years.  Very convenient for the code library.