# How to construct objects from files in a directory PHP

Tags: file, object, directory, migration, construct

I am writing a script to take care of my database migrations. I don't like using phinx, it doesn't allow for easy migrations for multiple databases.

My migrations are in directory

```
migrations/
```

I have read this question, and used it.

[PHP script to loop through all of the files in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202175/php-script-to-loop-through-all-of-the-files-in-a-directory)

```
foreach (glob("migrations/*.php") as $filename) {
    require_once $filename;
    $t = explode(".",$filename);
    $obj = strtolower($t[1]);
    $class = explode("/", $t[0]);
    ${$obj}= new $class[1]();     // make object from the class name
    ${$obj}->up();
}
```

The file in migrations/ is Directory.php, it is a migration for the directory database, it has a method up() which I am trying to call. I want to run this script after provisioning, or manually via command line. It seems to be constructing the class ok. Getting the following error though...

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Directory::up()

Comment: you cannot construct objects from php files, you can create instance of class defined in php file

Comment: Is that not the same thing? A want to create an instance of each class, so I can call the method up(), I thought the code I had would have worked?

Comment: it is not the same, not all php files contains classes and one php file can contain several classes, if you know that your php file for sure has class Directory and this class has method up, try to remove `${` and `}` around $obj, just `$obj = new $class... $obj->up();`

Comment: Didn't work, same error.