# Getting from a sub folder to the root failing

Tags: php, html, file, directory

I am trying to include a header/footer with php's `include_once`. I did not have any trouble until I created a sub-folder called, "states". I tried to include `include_once("header.php");` and it is failing. I know it is because it is not in the same directory, so I tried `include_once("/header.php");` and that did not work. I also tried doing this:

`include_once("header/states.php");`

`include_once("header/.php");`

What am I doing wrong for this to not get to the correct directory? I am trying to organize a bunch of files and I want to do this the correct way, so any help appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ./ to reference the current directory:

```
        include_once("./states/header.php");
```

That's assuming the file you are referencing from is in the directory shown. If it's in another directory ( like _notes ) then the directory one level up can be referenced by ../, thus:

```
        include_once("../states/header.php");
```

Comment: `Warning: include_once(./states/header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\sprayfoam\SFEI\states\Alabama-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php on line 70` I got the same error with your other way before you edited it.

Comment: What is the exact path of your index.html file/the file containing the include_once(..) line?

Comment: This is in Xampp right now, but will be on a cpanel. I just tried `<?php include_once(".\states\header.php"); ?>` and it did not help.

Comment: I am a bit confused about this ... What is the exact path of your index.html file/the file containing the include_once(..) line?

Comment: Sorry I was wrong about the backslashes, they're understood as forward slashes on all systems. Try the path you just used with trusty old forward slashes.

Comment: Are the two files in the same directory?

Comment: I am trying to include this into all my files, but the one I am having troubles with is with a sub folder. So it would be C:\xampp\htdocs\sprayfoam\SFEI\states\Alabama-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php

Comment: If the header.php file is at C:\xampp\htdocs\sprayfoam\SFEI\states then you need to go two levels up the file hierarchy, which would be include_once('../../states/header.php')

Comment: header.php is within the SFEI part.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant the file I was trying to include it within.

Comment: No . `Warning: include_once(../../states/header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\sprayfoam\SFEI\states\Alabama-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php on line 70`

Comment: It should be include_once('../../header.php') if the file is in the SFEI directory...

Comment: I think that did it! So, how did you know to put the `../../` the amount of times you did? I have other files within this that still aren't working and it would be nice to know.

Comment: If a file is in the same directory, it's ./filename.php. If it's in a directory one level higher, i.e. the parent directory itself, it's ../filename.php. If it's in another directory which is in the parent directory, it's ../someOtherFolder/header.php...have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202175/php-script-to-loop-through-all-of-the-files-in-a-directory

Comment: So to get within the layout folder and then a file within it, from the same Alabama file, would it be `href="../layout/styles/layout.css"`

Comment: Yes, if the layout folder is located in your parent folder.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help!