# Listing files from a folder give stat error due to filesize

Tags: php

I went through many Q&A but didn't find my solution.

I know there is a function GLOB but I am not using that as I saw somewhere that its not much flexible.

**WHAT I AM TRYING TO DO:**

I am trying to list files from a folder and show the size of it too.

**PROBLEM**

It gives me a stat error but the last file's size is being shown.

**PHP**

```
<?php
 $thelist = '';
 $count = 0;
 $filelist = array();
 if ($handle = opendir('./storage')) {
   while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
          if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
              $filelist[] = $file;
            /*$thelist .= '<li><a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></li>';*/
            $count = $count+1;
          }
       }
       closedir($handle);
}

for($index=0; $index<$count; $index++){
    $name = $filelist[$index];
    $size = number_format(filesize($filelist[$index]));
    $thelist .= '<li><a href="'.$name.'">'.$name.'</a>'.$size.'</li>';
}
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="list">
    <?php
    if($count<1){
        echo '<div id="empty_storage"><img src="icon.png"><br>Its lonely here!</div>';
    }
    else{
    ?>
        <ul>
        <?php echo $thelist; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

**NOTE**

I am trying this on WAMP.

**UPDATE**

My dump looks like this

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'icon (2).png' (length=12)
  1 => string 'icon.png' (length=8)
  2 => string 'new.png' (length=7)
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not crushing at trying to filesize.. directory?

Comment: Can u provide line where error occurs?

Comment: On line 18, in the snippet its on $size = number_format

Comment: can u print the $size without number_format ? - how does ur dump of $filelist Looks like ? can u add this above in ur question. maybe its due to the path.

Comment: As per your code, In `$filelist` array return files and directory both. Thats why you are getting `stat failed` error.

Comment: @KikiTheOne Yea its printing the values but for only the last file.

Comment: @hardiksolanki so what do you suggest to do?

Comment: @Ayan _how does ur dump of $filelist Looks like ?_

Comment: dump added in the question

Comment: first of all "SPACES" in filenames are not good practice. second check the answer below from @yergo he said what i thought. ur path is missing.

Comment: You should used `glob` instead of `opendir`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case your error reproduces as:

> PHP Warning:  filesize(): stat failed for testfile in /home/bnowakowski/storage/test.php on line 18
>   PHP Stack trace:
>   PHP   1. {main}() /home/bnowakowski/storage/test.php:0
>   PHP   2. filesize() /home/bnowakowski/storage/test.php:18
>   PHP Warning:  filesize(): stat failed for testdir in /home/bnowakowski/storage/test.php on line 18
>   PHP Stack trace:
>   PHP   1. {main}() /home/bnowakowski/storage/test.php:0
>   PHP   2. filesize() /home/bnowakowski/storage/test.php:18

resulting with:

```
<li><a href="testfile">testfile</a>0</li>
<li><a href="testdir">testdir</a>0</li>
```

What i had to do to make it working, was to change path of file it was asking for:

```
$name = $filelist[$index];
$size = number_format(filesize('./storage/' . $name));
```

to make it asking for size of file in proper location. It works even with symlinks or directories.

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot. Just one more thing, adding modified time, should I repeat the same thing? and how to sort the list of files as newest first?

Comment: At your place I would prefer to use [DirectoryIterator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202175/php-script-to-loop-through-all-of-the-files-in-a-directory) and collect fileinfo date part as key value in array of fileinfos. Then `ksort` it and prepare output as finishing touch.