# php dir function returns null even when files are there

Tags: php

I'm using php dir() function to get files from directory and loop through it.

```
$d = dir('path');

while($file = $d->read()) {
  /* code here */
}
```

But this returns false and gives

> Call to member function read() on null

But that directory exists and files are there.

Also, Is there any alternative to my above code?

Comment: Is path an absolute path? a relative path?  relative to where?

Comment: Use the `is_dir(path);` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look into [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dir.php) you will see:

> Returns an instance of Directory, or NULL with wrong parameters, or
>   FALSE in case of another error.

So `Call to member function read() on null` means that you got an error (I think that this `failed to open dir: No such file or directory in...`).

You can use [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) and [is_dir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php) for checking if the given path is a directory and if it really exists.

Example:

```
<?php
...
if (file_exists($path) && is_dir($path)) {
    $d = dir($path);

    while($file = $d->read()) {
      /* code here */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use this :

```
if ($handle = opendir('/path/to/files')) {
    echo "Directory handle: $handle\n";
    echo "Entries:\n";

    /* This is the correct way to loop over the directory. */
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        echo "$entry\n";
    }

    /* This is the WRONG way to loop over the directory. */
    while ($entry = readdir($handle)) {
        echo "$entry\n";
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
```

source : 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator(dirname('path'));
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) {
        var_dump($fileinfo->getFilename());
    }
}
```

Source: [PHP script to loop through all of the files in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202175/php-script-to-loop-through-all-of-the-files-in-a-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Please check your file path if your path is right. Then please try this code this may help you. Thanks

```
  <?php
$myfile = fopen("webdictionary.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
// Output one character until end-of-file
while(!feof($myfile)) {
  echo fgetc($myfile);
}
fclose($myfile);
?>
```